# How can I install Ubuntu on the second SATA hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, sata

How can I install Ubuntu on the second SATA hard drive?

Comment: he doesn't want to install it softly. he wants to make sure it's on that drive HARD. so hard it can't be formatted or deleted...EVER.

Comment: note the original question wording referred to "sata2 hard", instead of "second SATA hard drive".  it could refer to a SATA-II (3.0Gbps) drive, or could refer to the second drive, or could refer to the drive on the third SATA port (SATA0,1,2...).  it's hard to say without more information from the OP, and this is looking rather abandoned.

Comment: closing as this user never came back to follow up with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu supports most SATA hard disks and SATA controllers. You should just be able to install it normally.

If your chipset isn't supported, you need to contact the manufacturer.